# WCF Publish error: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, publish

I have a WCF web service I am tryiong to publish to IIS. I can view the wsdl fine but cannot add the service in Visual Studio 2010 via the Add Service Reference menu. I get the following error:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:4567/Service.svc?wsdl'.
The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:4567/Service.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:4567/Service.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:4567/Service.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I works great locally but not if published to IIS.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? Here is my web.config, I am new to WCF so might have missed something out, thanks:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 12):

I *truly* wish Microsoft would put better diagnostics in place to give us more targeted information on WCF configuration errors either at at build or runtime - I don't care which, but it has wasted so many hours of development time over the years it's unreal.

```
</rant>
```

For me, this ridiculously generic error's cause was this:

```
<endpoint address="mexTcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Should have been this:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Two hours of fart-arsing around trying to enable Net.Tcp for something that could have easily been highlighted in the IDE. Two hours!!!

Comment: I upvoted because you used the phrase `fart-arsing`.

Comment: me too, hee hee :-)

Comment: Only two hours?

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer here [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ec8429cc-387c-4bdd-ac59-69b37313d730/wcf-help-needed-metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-nettcplocalhost)

> When you define a net tcp protocol you need to ensure you are using `IMetadataExchange` contract defined in an endpoint contract. The service behaviour for this also needs to contain the `<serviceMetadata />` tag. From what i have understood, this is pretty much boilerplate code for your config if you are wanting to host and generate proxys / discover in VS.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Comment: @sundog... from your originally terrible quality answer, this has now been edited into a reasonable answer. Link only answers are frowned upon by the StackOverflow community and so you should always strive to provide answers with additional information taken from the linked page as now shown above. For more information on how to improve your answers, please see the [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page from the Help Center.

Answer (score 2):

As this is one of the first posts google shows up for this error, I want to participate with my solution:

I got a similar error while changing code in a system that was working well, but updating the reference on my development system failed. The reference is located inside a silverlight project and is related to a WCF integrated in the surrounding website (standard configuration I guess).

My error message included

> "WCF Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'Some
>   funny path'. The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response
>   message does not match the content type of the binding
>   (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)."

My website uses authorization roles, thats where the problem/solution was based. For updating the service reference I had to allow all users:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!--<authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>            
        </authorization>-->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="role-1,role-2"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Received basically the same error message when attempting to update service reference from one of our test servers.  Exact text (removed IPs etc):

```
There was an error downloading 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxxxxWSNew/Service.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.

The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxxxxWSNew/Service.svc'.

Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxxxxxWSNew/Service.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
```

This didn't seem right to me, so I used Fiddler to see what actual responses were coming back from the server when VS was attempting to generate a proxy from metadata.  Turns out the metadata  was pointing VS to the hostname that the server identifies itself as -- eg wwww.server.com.  Added the appropriate hosts file entry and the proxy generated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when one of my DataMember objects had a constructor. I'm not sure if it was the parameters for the constructor or something inside of it. But I was able to resolve by making the constructor a static method that returned a new type that it was previously constructing for.

Answer (score 0):

> I can view the wsdl fine but cannot add the service in Visual Studio 2010 via the Add Service Reference menu

Try using the WSDL tool, open a Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
wsdl.exe /out:c:\temp\WebService.cs /order www.webadress.com?wsdl
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the list of things that cause Error 415, in my case I forgot to add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attribute to a class that was used by the service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing empty constructor to one of the classes which the service returned. after adding it the error was removed.

```
    public ClassName() {}
```